# Selenium Webdriver [Java] Dynamic Table: Get the last value of a row (With Conditionals)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need help with the use of Selenium with a dynamic table.

I need to click over the LAST account which the status equals "ACTIVE" 
In the image appears the example.

[Dynamic Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZIa.png)

I was trying with the next code:

```
WebElement lastCredit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='tableinfo']/tbody/tr[last()]/td[3]/a and contains(text(), 'ACTIVE'") );
lastCredit.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I can't click over the accound and the program fails.

I was trying with 2 FOR:

```
    WebElement rows = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='tableinfo']/tbody/tr"));
    List<WebElement> columns = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='tableinfo']/tbody/tr[1]/td"));
    String[] array = new String[4];


    for(int i = 0; i <= rows.length; i = i ++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j <= columns.length; j = j ++)
      {     
        array[j] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='tableinfo']/tbody/tr[i]/td[j]/a")).getAttribute("value");
      }

      if (array[4] == “ACTIVE”) and (array[4].last()); {

          array.get(4).click();
}
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Why do you have a leading `(` in all the `xpath`s? this is your problem.

Comment: Do you mean the third (  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of the image, if your requirement is to click on the **last ACTIVE** status then try below simple snippet

```
List<WebElement> activeColumns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='ACTIVE']"));
activeColumns.get(activeColumns.size()-1).click();
```